# kafka console producer generate complex key/value

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka and would like to know if we can produce complex ConsumerRecord<String, CloudEvent> with kafka-conosle-producer.sh

Answer (score 0):

You can. Look at the `--line-reader` flag.

You need to implement your own `MessageReader` class.

However, if you're going to write code anyway, you may as well write an actual Java app that prompts for input itself and parses into the POJO you expect to produce